# Pandas merging value of two rows in columns of a single row

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I have data like this, it's output of a **groupby**:

```
numUsers = df.groupby(["user","isvalid"]).count()

                      count     
user       isvalid               
5          0.0         1336  
           1.0          387
```

But I need to have count of **count_valid** and **count_invalid** columns for each user, like this:

```
                    count_valid  count_invalid
user 
5                           387           1336
```

How can I do it in optimized way in Pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
out = (df.groupby(["user","isvalid"]).count()
         .rename({0: 'count_invalid', 1: 'count_valid'}, level=1)
         ['count'].unstack()
       )
```

Output:

```
isvalid  count_invalid  count_valid
user                               
5                 1336          387
```

Or, more generic if you have multiple columns, using a MultiIndex:

```
out = (df.groupby(["user","isvalid"]).count()
         .unstack().rename(columns={0: 'invalid', 1: 'valid'}, level=1)
       )
out.columns = out.columns.map('_'.join)
```

Output:

```
      count_invalid  count_valid
user                            
5              1336          387
```

Or from the original dataset with a `crosstab`:

```
pd.crosstab(df['user'], df['isvalid'].map({0: 'count_invalid', 1: 'count_valid'}))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can replace `groupby_count` by `value_counts`:

```
>>> (df.replace({'isvalid': {0: 'count_invalid', 1: 'count_valid'}})
       .value_counts(['user', 'isvalid']).unstack('isvalid')
       .rename_axis(columns=None))

      count_invalid  count_valid
user                            
5              1336          387
```

Another version with `pivot_table`:

```
>>> (df.replace({'isvalid': {0: 'count_invalid', 1: 'count_valid'}}).assign(count=1)
       .pivot_table(index='user', columns='isvalid', values='count', aggfunc='count')
       .rename_axis(columns=None))

      count_invalid  count_valid
user                            
5              1336          387
```